# Ansible: create a user with sudo privileges

Tags: ansible, sudoers

I have taken over a Ubuntu 14.04 server. It has a user called "deployer" (used with capistrano), and as such, it needs sudo privileges. With this setup, I can log into the server and do stuff like:

```
workstation> ssh deployer@myserver
myserver>  sudo apt-get install git
myserver> exit
workstation>
```

I am trying to figure out how to use Ansible (version 2.0.2.0 and python 2.7.3) to create a user called "deployer" and be able to log into the server with that id and then so sudo-ish things like "apt-get install". My playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: example
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Update apt cache
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600

  - group: name=sudo state=present

  - name: Add deployer user and add it to sudo
    user: name=deployer
          state=present
          createhome=yes
    become: yes
    become_method: "sudo"

  - name: Set up authorized keys for the deployer user
    authorized_key: user=deployer key="{{item}}"
    with_file:
      - /home/jaygodse/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

After running this playbook, I am able to ssh into the machine as "deployer", (e.g. ssh deployer@myserver) but if I run a sudo command, it always asks me for my sudo password.

I understand that the "deployer" user ultimately has to find its way into the visudo users file, but I cannot figure out which magical Ansible incantations to invoke so that I can ssh into the machine as  deployer and then run a sudo command (e.g. sudo apt-get install git") without being prompted for a sudo  password.

I have searched high and low, and I can't seem to find an Ansible playbook fragment which puts the user "deployer" into the sudo group without requiring a password.  How is this done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible: best practice for maintaining list of sudoers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359404/ansible-best-practice-for-maintaining-list-of-sudoers)

Answer (score 182):

Sometimes it's knowing what to ask. I didn't know as I am a developer who has taken on some DevOps work.

Apparently 'passwordless' or NOPASSWD login is a thing which you need to put in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

The answer to my question is at [Ansible: best practice for maintaining list of sudoers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359404/ansible-best-practice-for-maintaining-list-of-sudoers).

The Ansible playbook code fragment looks like this from my problem:

```
- name: Make sure we have a 'wheel' group
  group:
    name: wheel
    state: present

- name: Allow 'wheel' group to have passwordless sudo
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/sudoers
    state: present
    regexp: '^%wheel'
    line: '%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
    validate: 'visudo -cf %s'

- name: Add sudoers users to wheel group
  user:
    name=deployer
    groups=wheel
    append=yes
    state=present
    createhome=yes

- name: Set up authorized keys for the deployer user
  authorized_key: user=deployer key="{{item}}"
  with_file:
    - /home/railsdev/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And the best part is that the solution is idempotent. It doesn't add the line

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to `/etc/sudoers` when the playbook is run a subsequent time. And yes...I was able to ssh into the server as "deployer" and run sudo commands without having to give a password.

Comment: Please add the line `validate: 'visudo -cf %s'` to the end of your `lineinfile:` section to validate prior to saving. Messing up the sudoers file will lock you out of sudo access permanently.

Comment: `authorized_key` [accepts the key as a string](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/authorized_key_module.html) in the `key` parameter since v1.9

Comment: You can also create/copy a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, most distributions as a default include line for that...

Comment: Note that the `validate` command will probably need the full path to `visudo` to work.

Comment: @MattHughes `validate: '/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s'` <- is this what you mean?

Comment: Why do we add the user to wheel and not directly to sudo group?

```- name: "Granting Administrative Privileges"
  user:
    name: deployer
    groups: sudo
    append: yes```

Comment: Btw. if you are wondering, what the `%s` in `validate` means, it is the destination (dest) or path of the file that is supposed to be modified. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html).

Comment: For Ansible 2.3 and later, the parameter dest in lineinfile should be changed to path.

Comment: you forgot to ensure that file /etc/sudoers is present

Comment: I don't think its good to enable passwordless sudo for all sudo users.  It is suitable for automation accounts but not for human user accounts.  Better to just set `deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Comment: @SimonWoodside The Ansible's documentation page for "validate" says: _The validation command to run __before copying__ into place_. Why do you conclude it will check before __saving__?

Answer (score 23):

To create a user with sudo privileges is to put the user into `/etc/sudoers`, or make the user a member of a group specified in `/etc/sudoers`. And to make it password-less is to additionally specify `NOPASSWD` in `/etc/sudoers`.

Example of `/etc/sudoers`:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And instead of fiddling with `/etc/sudoers` file, we can create a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory since this directory is included by `/etc/sudoers` by default, which avoids the possibility of breaking existing sudoers file, and also eliminates the dependency on the content inside of `/etc/sudoers`.

To achieve above in Ansible, refer to the following:

```
- name: sudo without password for wheel group
  copy:
    content: '%wheel ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'
    dest: /etc/sudoers.d/wheel_nopasswd
    mode: 0440
```

You may replace `%wheel` with other group names like `%sudoers` or other user names like `deployer`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I added `validate: '/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s'` to make sure that the syntax is correct and won't block you if you have a typo.

Answer (score 6):

Although the initial answer is useful and popular, it can be updated based on the newest changes.

1. There is no group `wheel` in most modern distributions, but `sudo` is quite common
2. You don't need to touch (and break) system files in the `/etc` directory, but should use an extra path like `/etc/sudoers.d`
3. Use `true/false` boolean variables to be compatible with [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#boolean-variables)
4. I prefer to use variables for any kind of routine code, which can be copy/pasted between projects without changes.

This is the updated version:

```
- name: Add {{ sudo_user }} user
  user:
    name: "{{ sudo_user }}"
    groups: sudo
    append: true
    state: present
    createhome: true

- name: Make sudo without password for {{ sudo_user }} user
  copy:
    dest: /etc/sudoers.d/80-ansible-sudo-user
    content: "{{ sudo_user }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
    mode: 0440
```