# Unable to perform "git clone" on local system using Ansible

Tags: git, ansible

I am trying to clone a git repo on my local system. I have done this manually and it works fine, but when I try to do it via *Ansible*, it doesn't work out

Here is my play:

```yml
---
  - name: Create a directory on root
    file:
      path: "{{ local_home_dir }}/superb-queue"
      owner: "{{ local_user }}"
      group: "{{ local_user }}"
      state: directory
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: Clone the bitbucket queue repo locally
    git:
      repo: git@bitbucket.org:superbhq/queue-main.git
      dest: "{{ local_home_dir }}/superb-queue"
      clone: yes
      recursive: yes
      force: yes
      accept_hostkey: yes
      version: master
      key_file: "{{ local_home_dir }}/.ssh/id_rsa"
    become_user: "{{ local_user }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

The error I get is:

```bash
ASK [deploy-queue-main : Clone the bitbucket queue repo locally] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.0.3.219 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin '' /home/nishant/superb-queue", "msg": "fatal: destination path '/home/nishant/superb-queue' already exists and is not an empty directory.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "fatal: destination path '/home/nishant/superb-queue' already exists and is not an empty directory.\n", "stderr_lines": ["fatal: destination path '/home/nishant/superb-queue' already exists and is not an empty directory."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [10.0.4.36 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin '' /home/nishant/superb-queue", "msg": "Cloning into '/home/nishant/superb-queue'...\nWarning:********@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Cloning into '/home/nishant/superb-queue'...\nWarning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\ngit@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stderr_lines": ["Cloning into '/home/nishant/superb-queue'...", "Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.", "git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).", "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.", "", "Please make sure you have the correct access rights", "and the repository exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

The directory is empty on the localsystem, and I have the right keys. Not sure why this is happening

Comment: "*Here is my play*" ー what you posted is **not** a play, these are two tasks. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you post more questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two errors:

- `path '/home/nishant/superb-queue' already exists and is not an empty directory`
  If you already cloned your repo manually, make sure to delete that cloned repository folder before attempting it again through Ansible.
- `git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).`
  Make sure Ansible is running with the same account as yours, in order to use the same SSH keys in `~/.ssh`.
  Or define the [right ansible.cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34332794/6309).

As mentioned [in issue 5722](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/5722#issuecomment-262829350), try:

```yml
- name: Clone code repository
  git:  repo=example.com/repos/enterprise.git
        dest=/home/user/enterprise
        accept_hostkey=yes
        force=yes
        recursive=no
        key_file={{ userhome }}/.ssh/id_rsa
        depth={{ repo_depth }}
```

Here, `dest` should be the (non-existing) root folder of the cloned repository (not `~`, but `~/myrepo`).

Comment: For point A: i am cloning into a new folder , so i am a bit confused there

Comment: @NishantSingh for testing, can you try with `force: yes`?

Comment: with force yes/no , the directory is cloned coz of key_file, but the error regarding File exists remains

Comment: @NishantSingh And `/home/nishant/superb-queue` does not exist before you launching the Ansible playbook? I don't mean "empty", I mean "not existing"

Comment: @NishantSingh Can you try *without* creating it first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173190/discussion-between-nishant-singh-and-vonc).

Comment: @NishantSingh did you find the root cause?

Answer (score 10):

You are running the task concurrently on multiple host targets, each of which is delegating to the local host, effectively competing with each other:

> ```
> fatal: [10.0.3.219 -> localhost]: ...
> fatal: [10.0.4.36 -> localhost]: ...
> ```

Add `run_once: true` to the task.

Comment: I like that explanation (better than my answer) +1.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that you are using public repo if not then you should have added `key_file` and you probably need to add a user also.

Please have a look at the below solution for more info
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39735848/9857025

Let us know if this helped.

Comment: yes , i added the key file and that works.. but still the "msg": "fatal: destination path '/home/nishant/superb-queue' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: Clear the directory before you clone. The directory needs to be empty while you are cloning. Once it's done you are good to go

Comment: try deleting the 'superb-queue' and clone in 'nishant'. Let me know if that worked